# Spatial query on large data taking a lot of time - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, geospatial, postgis

I am working on queries on a large table in Postgres 13.4. It is a spatial dataset and it is spatially indexed. It does a self join to check which is the nearest neighbourhood and doesn't intersect with highway etc. Currently it takes about 10 min for a given cluster with 40,000 houses and eps as 150. I'm wondering if there is another way to write the query and make it more efficient.

```
select 
    a.house_id,
    dense_rank() over (order by a.house_id) - 1 as a,
    dense_rank() over (order by b.house_id) - 1 as b,
    st_distance(a.geog, b.geog) as distance,
    rank() over (order by a.house_id) - 1 as indxptr,
    a.household_count
from filtered_houses_29a a
join filtered_houses_29a b on ST_DWithin(a.geog, b.geog, 150) and a.house_id != b.house_id
where not ST_Intersects(
    (
        select st_union(l.way) geom
        from cluster c
        join planet_osm_line l on st_dwithin(c.concave_hull, l.way, 500)
        where c.cluster_id = 29
        and tunnel is null
        and (
            highway in ('motorway', 'motorway_link', 'primary', 'primary_link', 'secondary', 'secondary_link', 'tertiary', 'tertiary_link')
            or waterway is not null
            or railway is not null
        )
        
    ),
    ST_makeline(a.geom, b.geom)
) order by house_id, distance;
```

```
"Incremental Sort  (cost=13226204.51..73678993.05 rows=2416017 width=44) (actual time=524158.984..585834.585 rows=21701254 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: a.house_id, (st_distance(a.geog, b.geog, true))"
"  Presorted Key: a.house_id"
"  Full-sort Groups: 48355  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 30kB  Peak Memory: 30kB"
"  Pre-sorted Groups: 47300  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 124kB  Peak Memory: 131kB"
"  Buffers: shared hit=7483 read=1550 written=21, local hit=38974917 read=669 dirtied=222 written=19, temp read=969237 written=970139"
"  InitPlan 1 (returns $1)"
"    ->  Aggregate  (cost=7706.09..7706.10 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=123.938..123.940 rows=1 loops=1)"
"          Buffers: shared hit=7483 read=1550 written=21"
"          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.83..7646.46 rows=277 width=189) (actual time=1.931..85.104 rows=1311 loops=1)"
"                Buffers: shared hit=7483 read=1550 written=21"
"                ->  Index Scan using cluster_pkey on cluster c  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=1626) (actual time=0.017..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                      Index Cond: (cluster_id = 29)"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=2 read=1"
"                ->  Index Scan using planet_osm_line_way_idx on planet_osm_line l  (cost=0.54..7637.74 rows=41 width=189) (actual time=1.908..84.867 rows=1311 loops=1)"
"                      Index Cond: (way && st_expand(c.concave_hull, '500'::double precision))"
"                      Filter: ((tunnel IS NULL) AND ((highway = ANY ('{motorway,motorway_link,primary,primary_link,secondary,secondary_link,tertiary,tertiary_link}'::text[])) OR (waterway IS NOT NULL) OR (railway IS NOT NULL)) AND st_dwithin(c.concave_hull, way, '500'::double precision))"
"                      Rows Removed by Filter: 11342"
"                      Buffers: shared hit=7481 read=1549 written=21"
"  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=12914882.52..73381747.98 rows=2416017 width=44) (actual time=524158.639..577185.988 rows=21701254 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=7483 read=1550 written=21, local hit=38974917 read=669 dirtied=222 written=19, temp read=969237 written=970139"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=12914882.52..12920922.56 rows=2416017 width=84) (actual time=524158.588..527626.673 rows=21701254 loops=1)"
"              Sort Key: a.house_id"
"              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1911136kB"
"              Buffers: shared hit=7483 read=1550 written=21, local hit=38974917 read=669 dirtied=222 written=19, temp read=969237 written=970139"
"              ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.69..12427509.99 rows=2416017 width=84) (actual time=163.268..499233.733 rows=21701254 loops=1)"
"                    Buffers: shared hit=7483 read=1550 written=21, local hit=38974917 read=669 dirtied=222 written=19"
"                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.69..12391269.73 rows=2416017 width=76) (actual time=156.770..477898.769 rows=21701254 loops=1)"
"                          Buffers: shared hit=7483 read=1550 written=21, local hit=38974917 read=669 dirtied=222 written=19"
"                          ->  Index Scan using filtered_houses_29a_house_id on filtered_houses_29a b  (cost=0.29..3723.81 rows=49301 width=68) (actual time=0.375..44.831 rows=49301 loops=1)"
"                                Buffers: local hit=49234 read=136 dirtied=1 written=4"
"                          ->  Index Scan using filtered_houses_29a_geog on filtered_houses_29a a  (cost=0.40..251.21 rows=5 width=72) (actual time=0.116..9.548 rows=440 loops=49301)"
"                                Index Cond: (geog && _st_expand(b.geog, '150'::double precision))"
"                                Filter: ((house_id <> b.house_id) AND st_dwithin(geog, b.geog, '150'::double precision, true) AND (NOT st_intersects($1, st_makeline(geom, b.geom))))"
"                                Rows Removed by Filter: 351"
"                                Buffers: shared hit=7483 read=1550 written=21, local hit=38925683 read=533 dirtied=221 written=15"
"Planning Time: 2.390 ms"
"Execution Time: 588659.906 ms"
```

Comment: We need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question. Is there a compelling reason to create and index temp tables? That kind of operation takes a lot of time.

Comment: What is `create index filtered_houses_{cluster_id}_house_i` ? do the `{}` assume some kind of dynamic SQL ? (and since the TEMP table is guaranteed to be private to the session, you don't need a varying table/index name)

Comment: yes passing cluster_id dynamically ; but even for a single cluster id it is taking 10 min but that cluster has around 40000 houses.

Comment: Please show the `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, not just EXPLAIN.

Comment: Does your table really have two columns spelled `geom` and `geog`?

Comment: You query involves a table named cluster, but your plan doesn't mention it.  What is it?

Comment: updated the explain thanks

Answer (score 0):

As it is, the query is finding ALL nearby houses, and for the ones within a given "cluster" polygon, it ensures the line between two houses does not cross a street (etc).

The conceptual fault is that houses outside of the given "cluster" should be filtered out. The query plan indicates a sort of 2,416,017 which seems quite high when considering 40,000 houses within 150m of each others.

--> filter `filtered_houses_29a` using the cluster polygon